# pdf of two independent uniform distributions

Tags: probability

What would PDF look like for the sum of two independent uniform distributions on [a, b]? I was able to find the answer if they are defined on [0,1] but I want more general answer!

Comment: How did you find the specific answer you cited? What are the obstructions you see in generalizing that?

Answer (score 2):

The PDF of two added uniform distributions $U[a,b]$ and $U[a,b]$ will be $\Lambda[2a,2b]$, where $\Lambda$ is the [Symmetric Triangle Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution)

Answer (score -1):

If $U$ is uniformly distributed over $[a,b]$, $\frac{U-a}{b-a}$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$.